# How to get string values in RDD while implementing spark fp growth?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-mllib

I have successfully joined `userID` with `match` in the query below.

```
var queryToGroupCustomers = "SELECT yt.userID as player," +
  " concat_ws(\",\", collect_set(match)) AS matchesPlayedOn" + //concat_ws()
  " FROM recommendationengine.sportsbookbets_orc yt" +
  " where yt.userID is not null " + leagueCondition + "'" +
  " GROUP BY yt.userID"
```

now I would like to pass the columns into an RDD to be used in the algorithm. My implementation on this is with a generic row format `val transactions: RDD[Array[String]] = results.rdd.map( row => row.get(2).toString.split(","))` but is giving me the below error;

```
17/03/27 23:28:51 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 29)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.get(rows.scala:200)
```

An example of the joined data set is below;

```
ff6e96d4-e243-4046-8e02-ce3d4b459a5d    Napoli - Crotone, AC Milan - Juventus, Torino - Juventus, AS Roma - AC Milan, Empoli - Bologna, AC Milan - Internazionale, Genoa - AC Milan, Sassuolo - Chievo Verona, Sassuolo - Genoa
```

My full implementation of the algorithm as of yet, is as follows;

```
// Has all customers and their bets
var queryToGroupCustomers = "SELECT yt.userID as player," +
  " concat_ws(\",\", collect_set(match)) AS matchesPlayedOn" + //concat_ws()
  " FROM recommendationengine.sportsbookbets_orc yt" +
  " where yt.userID is not null " + leagueCondition + "'" +
  " GROUP BY yt.userID"

println("Executing query: \n\n" + queryToGroupCustomers)
var results = hc.sql(queryToGroupCustomers).cache()
val transactions: RDD[Array[String]] = results.rdd.map( row => row.get(2).toString.split(","))

// Set configurations for FP-Growth
val fpg = new FPGrowth()
  .setMinSupport(0.5)
  .setNumPartitions(10)

// Generate model
val model = fpg.run(transactions);

println("\n\n Starting FPGrowth\n\n")

model.freqItemsets.collect().foreach { itemset =>
  println(itemset.items.mkString("[", ",", "]") + ", " + itemset.freq)
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a row with 2 fields, and `row.get(2)` gets the value of its third field (fields in row are 0-based, as usually); of course it's an error. To get `matchesPlayedOn`, use `row.get(1)` or just `row(1)`.